# How to delete categories of user?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I try to delete categories of user like as:

```
Category::with('user', Auth::user()->id)->where("user_id", $id)->delete();
```

Category model has relationship:

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user_id', 'id');
}
```

But it does not work for me

`User model`:

```
public function categories()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Category');
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try without with():

```
Category::where("user_id", $id)->delete();
```

**Update** after the User model code addition:

The inverse of a **belongsToMany** relation is another **belongsToMany**, the inverse of a **belongsTo** is a **hasMany** or a **hasOne**.

You have to decide which relations between User and Category you want, because a **belongsTo** doesn't work with an inverse **belongsToMany**.

From what you wrote in answer and comments seems that you want a Many to many relationship (you have an intermediate table) in this case you have to use **belongsToMany** in both models and then you can use this code to delete user categories assignement:

```
$user->categories()->detach()
```

Comment: Then returns me: `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'user_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: delete from `categories` where `user_id` = 1)`

Comment: If Category model belongs to a User, like you wrote in your code, category table should have a column user_id

Comment: I have three tables: User, Categories, User_categories, so I need to delete from User_categories table

Comment: The code you wrote doesnt follow your tables structure. If you have an intermediate table you have to use ManyToMany relationship. i.e: belongsToMany('App\User');

Comment: Yes, in model `User` I have this: `public function categories()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Category');
    }`

Comment: But you wrote the code for the Category model and the user() function in the Category model is wrong, should be belongsToMany('App\User')

Comment: I have in `Category` model:  `public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'user_id', 'id');
    }`

Comment: the wrong relation is in the Category model, shoul be: public function user(){ return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');}. I wrote this almost 3 times. And you added the User model after my answer

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to flesh out how they will relate. Right now, based on your relationship code, the Categories table should have an `user_id` in it.

This is what the relationship on the Category model should look like:

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
}
```

And you need a table with the name `category_user` to make the relationship work. Here's an example of what the migration would look like:

```
Schema::create('category_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned();
    $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
    $table->timestamps();

    $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories');
    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
})
```

Then you'd be able to add users to categories in the following ways:

```
$category->users()->attach(Auth::id());
Auth::user()->categories()->attach([ 1, 2, 3 ... ]);
```

And remove:

```
$category->users()->detach(Auth::id());
Auth::user()->categories()->detach([ 1, 2, 3 ... ]);
```

You can also use `sync` which would detach any element not on your array and attach any element not currently attached:

```
Auth::user()->categories()->sync([ 1, 2, 3, ... ]);
```